# Debugging Meteor on intelliJ IDEA

Tags: debugging, meteor, intellij-idea

I have IDEA 2107.3 version ultimate edition. To debug the meteor codebase i added a plugin. But the debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoints i specify in the editor.In the debug console I keep seeing this message:

> => App running at: http://localhost:3000/
>   W20180214-00:22:16.105(5.5)? (STDERR) Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62959/c4ddad73-b88b-4279-8c59-fa8dc4057df0
>   W20180214-00:22:16.106(5.5)? (STDERR) For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
>   W20180214-00:22:16.106(5.5)? (STDERR) Debugger attached.

The debugger does stop in server/main.js file of the default meteor project but no where else.Here is how my debug configuration looks like.[image]

Please help.

Comment: There is similar issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29693. You could describe your problem in comments.